# Notification Sound Stops on Click

Tags: android

I use the following code to add the notification, and in the notification I add two features, one is Sound and other is flashing light.

```
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
                int icon = R.drawable.icon;
                CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
                long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
                RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.cutomnotification);
                contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1,"Custom");
                notification.contentView = contentView;
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MyClass.class);
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(v.getContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
                notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
                notification.sound=android.provider.Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI;
                notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
                notification.ledOnMS = 300;
                notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
                notification.flags=Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT|Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS|Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
                mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

In this I also use the custom layout,

Now I have two questions,

1) The sound plays and it stops when user clicks on notification tab,but I want to continue the sound until user press any button on custom layout.

2) I add a button in custom layout now i can implement onClickListener() on it.

Comment: Hey anyone used the notification in android, please give me some suggestions.

Comment: can please anyone give me the answer

Answer (score 2):

Add this code after `notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;`

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; //Do not clear the notification
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the **NotificationCompat.Builder** object without using **setSound().** This will create a notification without any sound.

```
 notification = mBuilder    
            .setStyle(notiStyle)   
            .setSmallIcon(notificationIcon)  
            .setTicker(title)  
            .setWhen(0)  
            .setAutoCancel(true)  
            .setContentTitle(title)  
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)  
            .build();
```